# html <object> size to fit content of object

Tags: php, html, object, height

I'm using the [object] tag to display the text of a .txt file. The object is within a div. When the object loads the text it sets up in a frame, which I can define height and width. However, setting the height to auto, or 100% does nothing. No matter what I do the area in which the text is displayed is small, with scroll bars. I want the div that the object is contained in, along with the object itself, to stretch to show all the text.

Here is the line:

```
<object type="text/html" data="./docs/description_a.html" style="width:100%; "></object>
```

But no matter what I do I cannot get it to stretch based on the length of the text. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I wasn't aware objects could even do this! Is there any reason you're not using a simple `<pre>` tag and including the text in the document? (I notice you tagged this as PHP so it should be possible). When using `object` for flash, CSS widths/heights have always worked for me, but maybe the object this is inside of doesn't have a width set?

Comment: I was initially setting the height with a static number (i.e., height:950px;), but the issue is when you view the page on a smaller screen, a mobile phone for example, the text of the object gets cutoff.

Comment: Just add an object { width: 100%; height: 100%;} or similar in your CSS. I believe if you already have a CSS file, the attributes there will probably override ypur HTML tag attributes, e.g. if you have * { ... } defined.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/XAaMV/4/

You can use jQuery to dynamically set the height and width:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#obj").width($("#cont").width());
    $("#obj").height($("#cont").height());

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="cont">
<object id="obj" width="" height="" data="www.google.com"></object>
 <div>
```

---

**Solution 2**

```
<div>
<object width="600" height="900" data="www.google.com"></object>
 <div>
```

CSS

```
div{

    height:600px;
    width:900px;
}
```

Comment: OK - so I admit, I'm fairly new to jquery. Where do I put the jquery code? I tried putting it within a php block but it just prevented my page from loading all together. The block was first just above the start of my html code, then I tried just before the end of my head tag.

Comment: @DrBankHead1 You would put this code in `<script>` tags anywhere on an HTML page (within the body) or even on a `.js` page.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Evan. That seemed to simple.

Alas, still no luck. The object is still in a small frame within the div.

Comment: @DrBankHead1 Did you check out the fiddle I made? Did that not do what you were looking for? IF not, how does what I made differ from your markup? I will change it accordingly once you let me know, thanks.